# what is a good antonym for the word "abstract"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, antonyms

I am writing a text in which I am discussing that teaching "facts" is not sufficient since they are abstract and the idea behind them is more important. 
I need an antonym for the word "abstract" to be able to further develop my point of view.

For example, if I say: "The concepts and the ideas behind every physics formula are "the antonym of abstract"."

Comment: Could you supply an example sentence, please, or more about your proposed use?

Comment: The common term is ***concrete***.

Comment: Downvoted for failing to simply Google "synonym abstract" and consult one of the 6-8 online thesauri that would find for you.

Comment: Antonyms like *concrete* or *specific* immediately jump to mind, and can be looked up in a thesaurus of your liking. However, the elephant in the room is that the sentence is horrible nonsense to begin with. All concepts and ideas are abstract by definition. Toss away, rewrite from scratch.

Answer (score 20):

How about **concrete**?

Defined in Mirriam Webster as:

> characterized by or belonging to immediate experience of actual things
>   or events

In the software development world, we often use "concrete" as the opposite of "abstract".

Answer (score 6):

You might want to try **tangible**, or **palpable**.

**palpable**:

> 1.readily or plainly seen, heard, perceived, etc.;obvious; evident:
>
> 2.capable of being touched or felt; tangible.

**tangible**:

> 1.capable of being touched; discernible by thetouch; material or substantial.
>
> 2.real or actual, rather than imaginary or visionary:

Example:

"His happiness was **palpable**, it could be felt emanating from him."

"Their love was almost **tangible**, and nobody could deny its existence."

(dictionary.com)

Comment: In fact, I have another point to ask: The facts are subjective or objective? I mean the fact itself should be more objective and the ideas behind are more subjective. That is making my explanation tough.

Comment: Facts are objective, opinions are subjective, but consider posting a separate question about it.

Comment: Whereas palpable or tangible can be antonyms of *abstract*, they can't be applied to concepts or ideas

Answer (score 2):

antonyms are actual, concrete, material